# How a peer on private lan is connected to another peer on another private lan in bittorrent

Tags: p2p, lan, nat, bittorrent, peer

How the peaces of data are being transferred to a client behind the router (private lan)

I know that every peer is connected to a tracker (Public IP) initially but tracker doesn't involve in transfer of data.

I've read many answers on stackoverflow and superuser about bittorrent working but I didn't get the answer.

I would really appreciate if someone explains it in detail similar to this answer https://superuser.com/questions/401802/how-do-ip-answer-packets-reach-their-destination-inside-of-a-private-lan

I'm curious to know whats happening on the router for torrent traffic.

Comment: What didn't you understand from the answers posted to the question you linked? The stuff it talks about is fully applicable to decentralized p2p protocols such as bittorrent.

Comment: @Sneftel  I didn't understand. how can centralized is fully applicable to decentralized?

Comment: Similar questions that I've seen...but no answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018627/how-do-bittorrents-connect-with-eachother?rq=1 (He says not possible)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367603/connecting-p2p-over-nat?rq=1

Comment: A partially decentralised protocol which used a central server for NAT punch-through would have complications. But bittorrent isn't one of those. Connections to a private IP are done through port forwarding; connections *from* a private IP are done like all connections from a private IP; there's nothing particuarly unique going on.